# No result in C++ tag

Tags: bug, tags

In Stack Overflow when I select questions filtered by [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) I will nothing. What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: related: [Cant see any questions with sql-server tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217477/cant-see-any-questions-with-sql-server-tag). I think it is a temporary caching issue.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+F5 several times.

Comment: Usually this means one of the servers in the cluster got confused. Reload and move on, it'll auto-correct.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It is happening a little more persistently now; two more dupes have come in since this one was posted.

Comment: @Robert Harvey It happens sometimes not all the times, that's why I added a screen-shot to the post. I am just curious to know the reason, not a big deal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I dropped a message into the Teacher's Lounge.